# Graphing $f(x) = x(-1)^x$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, open-map

My analysis TA gave $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x) = x(-1)^x$ as an example of an open function (i.e. $f$ maps any open set $S$ to some open set $f(S)$) which is not continuous.

I was trying to work through this function with the example $S = (-0.1, 3.1)$. My thought was that $f$ could only be defined when $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ as otherwise the product would include $\sqrt{-1}$, which is undefined in $\mathbb{R}$. For example, $f(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{\sqrt{-1}}{2}$, which doesn't exist in $\mathbb{R}$ as far as I know. Therefore $f(S) = \{0, -1, 2, -3\}$, which is closed, hence $f$ cannot be open.

My TA said that it's defined everywhere on the reals but is discontinuous at 0, and drew [the following graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOUCX.jpg). My own graph was essentially the "sharp" points without the lines connecting them. This graph seems to imply $f(\frac{1}{2})$ maps to $-\frac{1}{2}$, which would only be the case if the y-axis was imaginary as far as I know, but he reiterated that they're the reals, and conceded that it was "hard to explain".

I haven't worked much with $\mathbb{C}$ or roots of $-1$ before so I'm sure I have some misunderstanding.

Comment: I can't come up with a single thing about that plot that I believe is correct, to be honest.

Comment: [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5B%7BRe%5Bx+%28-1%29%5Ex%5D%2CIm%5Bx+%28-1%29%5Ex%5D%7D%2C%7Bx%2C-3%2C3%7D%5D) is the plot.

Comment: $f(x) = x(-1)^x$ is not $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: The only meaning one can give of $(-1)^x$ is $(-1)^x=i^{2 x}=e^{i \pi x}$ generating a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$... Tell your TA !!!

Comment: I was quite puzzled so I am glad to know my thinking was on the right track. I'll follow up with him using the feedback here, thank you!